# Can't run app engine project with maven layout

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, maven

Having created maven project under Eclipse I configured app engine settings and set my WAR directory to target/Site-0.0.1-Snapshot (I'm using app engine plugin). Deploying the project to app engine works just fine however I can't get the project running locally. When I start it just copies the entire contents of target/Site-0.0.1-Snapshot to target/Site-0.0.1-Snapshot/WEB-INF remaining the lib directory empty and throwing ClassNotFoundException. What can cause such strange behavior? May be I'm having something misconfigured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.
The problem has been solved checking the "Launch and deploy from this directory" option.